# Referencing an exchange-calendar

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to access a shared calendar in Outlook with VBA?

The active user has all rights to access and edit the calendar, excluding the parent-folder itself. We have no problems accessing the calendar via Outlook, but we just can't find a way to access it via VBA-Code.

How do you access such a calendar via code?

This...

```
 objFolder = objNS.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objRecipient, 9)
```

... is not working as my own folder is just being returned, even though the objRecipient ist not myself.

```
For indx = 1 To objNS.Folders.Count
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders(indx)
Next indx
```

... is not working either as the needed calendar is not included in the returned values.

I would be grateful for any advice, thanks & greets!

Comment: Are you sure objRecipient is correctly resolved? I have never seen GetSharedDefaultFolder returning the Calendar folder of the current user instead of the user specified as the parameter.

Comment: It resolves correctly as far as I can tell. On debug it even resolves to the correct title, so thaz shouldnt be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After some Errortracking we camr to the conclusion, that the Exchangeserver didn't synchronize correctly. Resetting the userprofile helps with this issue!